# Battery Charging circuit problem

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, battery-charging, circuit-design

I want to charge a 3.7v battery of 3000mAh.

I am using the battery charging circuit based LM317(from internet source)

[image]

I have connected the components by supplying input voltage of 9v and while checking the output voltage i am getting 0.6v only

while checking with 12v also i am getting same 0.6v

Comment: Besides that you don't tell what you chose for Ra, how and where did you measure these 0.6V ? between GND and BAT- ? Was a load connected or not? What kind of load?

Comment: Is the [Circuit from here](http://320volt.com/lm317-3-6v-lithium-ion-pil-sarj/) - you should provide a link. Use web or OS tool to translate to English. As PLasmaHH says - you must say WHERE you are measuring, what your load is, what your resistor values are & anything else you have done that is not absolutely identical to the circuit shown. 
This is not a very good circuit. Where are you located. It may be possible to buy an IC that does a MUCH better job than this.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Look to the right. Ra is 1 ohm. Also supported by the current calculation at upper right.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: at the right of what? I can't see a 1 anywhere, and it is a bit too much to expect being able to guess that from formulas and descriptions that don't mention Ra, nor are they in English.

Comment: @PlasmaHH the Ra i have connected is 1k. And i have checked between BAT+ and BAT-. I removed Ra also checked between BAT+ and BAT- voltage of 0.6 remains the same. I think Ra is just to limit the current flow to the battery. My case i want only the voltage.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes the same English verson http://320volt.com/en/lm317-3-6v-lithium-ion-pil-sarj/

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have just connected my multimeter n have checked it. Not any load

Comment: @NaveenRaja RA is designed to be 1 OHM. 1 k for Ra will allow the circuit to provide 1 mA at besst and as the IC and resistors need more than that to operate it will shut down - as it does. EITHER set Ra = 1 OHM or short RA = 0.0 Ohms to eliminate current limiting - FOR TESTING ONLY

Comment: Mark a copy of the cirrcuit withvalues YOU are using. Give the components thenames in the formulas. eg R4 does not appear on the diagram (clue R4 = RA BUT others shpould not have to work that out).

Answer (score 2):

The output of the LM317 (LDO) is based on the resistors at the output and the voltage reference (1,25V based onthe [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf)) and not of the input voltage (12V or 9V).
when you choose the resistor Ra, you have tow cases:

1. If the transistor is blocked:
   Vout = Vbat+ = 1,25*(1+(Req/220)+ Req*Iadj; 220: resistor 220 ohm.
   Req= (R2//R1)+Ra
   and Vbat = VRa
2. If you choose Ra to saturate the transistor then you have Vout=V220 (resistor 220 ohm).

Take example of Ra=0 ohm, you have:
Vout = Vbat+ = 1,25*(1+(Req/220); with: Req=R1//R2
Vout = 1,25*(1+530/220)=4,26V;
Vbat-=0;

The transistor in this case is blocked.

Comment: can you suggest me any solution or any alternative circuit

Comment: You can use the LP2951 voltage regulator is more suitable for your application

Answer (score 0):

Ra value is 1ohm (not 1K) for 600mA battery charging current. (0.6V/1ohm=600mA. Where 0.6V is Vbe of BC639 transistor.)
If you get only 0.6V battery charging voltage(4.2V), check for defective components, their pin configurations and any possible short/open circuits or wrong wiering etc.....

Answer (score -1):

Try checking LM317 for damage. It's missing blocking diode between LM317 output and BAT+, this prevents battery current from flowing back into the LM317 output pin if the input power source is removed.